# Get controller method caller (3rd party webservice)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to retrieve the URL of a 3rd party webservice calling my controller method?
Things like Request.Current.Url refer to my own URL (/someController/someAction/).

The 3rd party webservice is sending HTTP POST data to my /someController/someAction and I wish to send back a HTTP POST message to the caller of the method, the 3rd party webservice, without using

```
return Content["some response"]
```

which will force me to exit the method. Since the answer is plain text I would like to send it using HTTP Post.

What I actually try to do is respond to the calling webservice without exiting my method (return Content() will exit) so I can call other methods to process the data send to me by the webservice. I want to first tell the webservice I received their stuff and than process, in this way when a processing error occurs the webservice at least will not resend old data. Is there another way to do this than building your own HTTP post?

Comment: Did you try HttpRequest.UserHostName? Or HttpRequest.Headers to inspect the host variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on Request.UrlReferer, but your idea seems not that good. The best solution would be propably to start new thread for data processing and stick to `return Content`.

Comment: Exactly the way I implemented it in the meanwhile :). Marked as final answer. I suspect UrlReferer is no luck by the way when since the service calls the method at once so there is no referer. The URL Referrer returns a value only when the user reaches the current page through a link from the previous page I believe but I did not test it.